# SQL union all but flag groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm quite novice to SQL, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I have 3 sql queries that return 3 different sets of results (students, staff, customer), the columns are all the same

```
id first name last name address zip group 1 group 2 group 3
```

each select statement for each group populates one of the group columns with the type (students, staff, customer), the union all between select statements gets me all 3 groups in 1 table...but I want the duplicates..merged and have the groups reflect from all 3 queries?

```
id first name last name address zip group 1 group 2 group 3
1  Bob        Smith     bkr st  33  STUDENT
2  Zoe        Apple     trk av  44          STAFF   CUSTOMER
2  Zoe        Apple     trk av  44  STUDENT
```

becomes:

```
id first name last name address zip group 1 group 2 group 3
1  Bob        Smith     bkr st  33  STUDENT
2  Zoe        Apple     trk av  44  STUDENT STAFF   CUSTOMER
```

here's more or less the prototype select statements with union:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, student_FN AS'FIRST NAME', student_LN AS 'LAST NAME', ADDRESS, ZIP. 'STUDENT' AS 'GROUP 1'. '' AS 'GROUP 2','' AS 'GROUP 3' 
WHERE STUDENT_STATUS IN ('ENROLLED')
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT ID, STAFF_FN AS 'FIRST NAME', STAFF_LN AS 'LAST NAME', ADDRESS, ZIP. '' AS 'GROUP 1'. 'STAFF' AS 'GROUP 2','' AS 'GROUP 3' 
WHERE STAFF_RECORD IN ('ACTIVE')
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT ID, CUS_FN AS 'FIRST NAME', CUS_LN AS 'LAST NAME', ADDRESS, ZIP. '' AS 'GROUP 1'. '' AS 'GROUP 2','CUSTOMER' AS 'GROUP 3' 
WHERE CUSTOMER_SHOPPED IN ('STORE')
```

each select tables pulls the columns from slightly different places..
many thanks!

Comment: Is the DISTINCT purposely whereas you do not want duplicates

Comment: Single quotes are for character literals (aka string values), use double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. colunm aliases.

Comment: Navoneel - the distinct is for non duplicates within each group

Comment: Jarih - thanks for the tip!

Comment: Are these group1 ,2 ,3 column names in your table?

Comment: `AS 'FIRST NAME'` is invalid (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes, tag dbms used! You've got nice answers, but not working with all dbms products...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ID, 
       "FIRST NAME", 
       "LAST NAME", 
       ADDRESS, 
       ZIP, 
       MAX(CASE "GROUP TYPE" WHEN 'STUDENT' THEN 'STUDENT' END) "GROUP 1", 
       MAX(CASE "GROUP TYPE" WHEN 'STAFF' THEN 'STAFF' END) "GROUP 2", 
       MAX(CASE "GROUP TYPE" WHEN 'CUSTOMER' THEN 'CUSTOMER' END) "GROUP 3"
FROM
(SELECT ID, student_FN AS "FIRST NAME", student_LN AS "LAST NAME", ADDRESS, ZIP, 'STUDENT' AS "GROUP TYPE"
 FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENT_STATUS IN ('ENROLLED')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ID, STAFF_FN AS "FIRST NAME", STAFF_LN AS "LAST NAME", ADDRESS, ZIP, 'STAFF' AS "GROUP TYPE"
 FROM STAFF WHERE STAFF_RECORD IN ("ACTIVE")
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ID, CUS_FN AS "FIRST NAME", CUS_LN AS "LAST NAME", ADDRESS, ZIP, 'CUSTOMER' AS "GROUP TYPE" 
 FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_SHOPPED IN ('STORE')
) AS ILQ
GROUP BY ID, "FIRST NAME", "LAST NAME", ADDRESS, ZIP
```

Note that this will return multiple rows for the same ID if any of the name or address details are different.

Comment: thanks! I'll give this a try, it makes quite alot of sense, i'm wrapping my head around GROUP BY (after i verify that it's a MS Sql server and not something else)

Comment: I feel this is close, unfortunately I didn't have access to that one sandbox env today, but was doing something similar with 3 tables of students, faculty, staff - more complex selects and joins..but...the logic applies IMO...but I'm getting syntax errors... (trying to figure out how to paste code in here...it's really big though..)

Comment: This works beautifully! And I learned a lot from this and the other solutions! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, address, zip, MAX(group1), MAX(group2), MAX(group3)
FROM YOUR_TABLES
GROUP BY id, first_name, last_name, address, zip
```

Comment: hi Ankit, i'm not sure that would work since each of the columns in each group pulls from a different place e.g. CUS_FN for 'first name" for a customer, STUDENT_FN for student's first name! (made the edits in original post to make clearer!

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach avoing `Union`:

```
;WITH 
S as (SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENT_STATUS IN ('ENROLLED') ),
F as (SELECT * FROM STAFFS WHERE STAFF_RECORD IN ('ACTIVE') ),
C as (SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_SHOPPED IN ('STORE') )

SELECT 
   DISTINCT COALESCE(S.ID, F.id, C.id ) as ID, 
            COALESCE(S.'FIRST NAME', F.'FIRST NAME', C.'FIRST NAME') 
            as 'FIRST NAME', 
            COALESCE(S.'LAST NAME', F.'LAST NAME', C.'LAST NAME' ) as 'LAST NAME',
            COALESCE(S.ADDRESS, F.ADDRESS, C.ADDRESS ) as ADDRESS,
            COALESCE(S.ZIP, F.ZIP, C.ZIP ) as ZIP,
            'STUDENT' AS 'GROUP 1',
            'STAFF' AS 'GROUP 2',
            'CUSTOMER' AS 'GROUP 3' 
FROM 
     S
FULL OUTER JOIN 
     F on  F.id = S.id
FULL OUTER JOIN 
     C on C.id = COALESCE( S.id, F.id )
```

Comment: oh i see! interesting! I'll give this a try! just read up on coalesce, similar to a case statement!

Comment: Do you really want those conditions in the WHERE clause when it's a FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @jarlh, oh!! Nice!! Thanks. I try to fix it.

Comment: @jarlh , my new solution looks dirty. Do you have a better approach without CTE?

Comment: Note that full outer joins aren't available if using MySQL.

Comment: @MarkBannister, you are right. But, question is tagged as SQL. Any case, I going to delete my answer in a minute ;)

Comment: @danihp, too bad OP didn't specify dbms. I'll wait and see.

Comment: @danihp: I agree with jarlh - I would wait and see which DBMS is being used.

Comment: Hello, native SQL (Microsoft)

Comment: @Jim, MS SQL Server is not native SQL. SQL is a language specified by ANSI/ISO.

Comment: Will doublecheck on the dbms!

Comment: @jarlh, translated to T-SQL. But not sure this is the best approach. Perhaps  MarckBannister approach is better.

Comment: @jim,  T-sql is the syntax for MS SQL